# Search on a server

Tags: windows-server-2003, search

I have a Win 2003 server that hosts hundreds of web sites.   I'm constantly using the rotten Windows search tool to find files via RDP.   My typical search would be to find any mention of things in the code of the sites, for instance a variable name, or a hard-coded email address.

Google desktop might be the ticket if it was a workstation, but the desktop search only runs when the user is logged in (which is pretty much never).

I'd love to find a better file finder! Maybe something like Mac OS/X spotlight.

The key is that it has to index as a service, so a user doesn't have to be logged in.

Comment: No taglines, please. (read the FAQ)

Comment: Windows Search? I know it runs as a service.  Watch out for performance issues during initial index...

Comment: when you use windows search are you putting an ! in front of whatever your search for?  if not then your search will be painfully slow. Of course this won't work if you don't have the indexing service running.  Now if the complaint is that you want to not have to RDP in then you need to have the web sites indexed then you can one create a nice search portal for the content or you can just use the basic one thats provided.

Answer (score -1):

[Download grep for windows.](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

Comment: Last time I checked, grep doesn't index files.

Comment: The OP didn't specify it had to index, just that it would be able to run when a user is not logged in. If you are greping you would not really need to index files. I may just have misunderstood his ultimate goal.

Comment: look again at his last sentence.